# Left Trim 'abc' and right trim 'xyz'

Tags: sql-server-2008

A vendor writes user defined data into a a single column as XML, I need to write an SQL query (2008 / 2012 / 2014) that pulls data from that column for a 3rd party application, here's an example of what is in the column

```
<udf><udf_date_ppe>15/12/2019</udf_date_ppe><udf_text_ppn>300965994</udf_text_ppn><udf_date_ved>8/12/2016</udf_date_ved><udf_text_vtno>417 - Working holiday</udf_text_vtno><udf_text_ppi>Taiwan</udf_text_ppi></udf>
```

The problem is I need to grab all the actual data not the XML and the XML isn't stored in the same order meaning I have to dynamically figure out the lengths to trim left and right.  For example, I want the date only inbetween this XML

```
<udf_date_ppe>15/12/2019</udf_date_ppe>
```

but I don't know how many characters are before it.  Once I figure out how to do one I can replicate for the other fields, this is only one user defined filed but at least the XML isn't going to change.  I only have view access to the server.

Bit of a pain I know but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please tag RDBMS you are using. Based on your question, it appears using XML parsing in some sort of procedure is better than using string manipulation commands or regex for this job

Comment: I know the tag will always be <udf_date_ppe> and I know the number of characters will I need after it will always be 10.

Comment: You really need to tell us which database you are using, as the string functions are highly vendor specific.

Comment: If I understand your question, the XML data is being stored into a column in an MS SQL 2008 server, but other databases using a similar product are using 2012 and 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to grab the 10 characters appearing inside the `<udf_date_ppe>` tags, you can use SQL Server's string functions and the following query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('<udf_date_ppe>', col) + 14, 10)
FROM yourTable
```

This assumes that there is only a single `<udf_date_ppe>` tag in the column.

Comment: This is perfect and elegant thank you so very, so much!